# Does WordPress store the username as a primary key in the database?

Tags: database, users

Does WordPress store the username as a primary key in the table in the database? I'm wondering why WordPress prevents admins from changing their username and this is the only thing I can think of.

PS There are many valid reasons to change a username. For example, the easy install program created a WordPress install and used the default username "admin".

Comment: No, the primary key is a numeric ID. You can easily see that in the database. Is that really a question?

Comment: it is probably for security purposes, but you can change it via the database. In future, maybe just create a new admin account and delete the other after using an installer.

Comment: @Toscho Can you add this as an answer? FYI I have limited access at the moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WP is not likely going to add this feature...

From https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14644, the main reason given by Nacin is:

> This is a caching issue. Additionally, it also breaks URLs and such, which is why I don't think administrators should be able to do it either.
>   Seems simple enough to relegate to a plugin, or a straight DB edit.
>   Suggesting wontfix.

Comment: Thanks for the info and the link. I can understand the reasons not to but in the other hand there are perfectly valid reasons and WordPress.com has this option. It might be good reasons for a user but admins, in my humble opinion, should have this option.

Comment: Yep I understand your point, but that would bring really unwelcomed complications if it's being added to core which has to stay the most simple possible.

Comment: Does WordPress itself create plug-ins? If they don't maybe they can consider it. That way they can add these features while keeping the core small in size.